# How can I view the license information of preprints on the arXiv?

Tags: arxiv, license, creative-commons

I'm interested in learning more about different types of licenses that are used for preprints on the arXiv. Upon checking some random articles on the website, I could not find the licenses under which they're distributed. Are they listed somewhere in the arXiv entry itself, or do I have to consult the relevant authors to learn more about the license that belongs to the preprint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below the download options for each article (i.e. "pdf", "postscript", etc.) there is a link in very small print labeled "license".

Comment: Ah I see now, I glossed over it. Thank you.